# How to encrypt one image inside another?

Tags: algorithm, encryption

I am looking for encryption mechanism (algorithm) to encrypt one meaningful image inside another, or one text inside another. Is it possible? please refer me to some existing works and algorithms.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You are indeed looking for steganography. There has been a lot of work done on images, but every algorithm offers something different. How big is the cover image compared to the secret? Is it important for the extracted secret to be lossless? What is the format of the cover image? Do you care if someone blindly modifies the cover image and accidentally, or intentionally destroys your secret? Answering questions like that can filter your results to see if there is anything existing that fits your requirements. But remember, you can't have it all. Compromises may have to be made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography).  It's a broad topic, but the Wikipedia article will get you started.